how i can make the numer of subsection in right side
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
 \usepackage{nopageno}
 \let\oldsection\section% Store \section
\renewcommand{\section}{% Update \section
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}% Update equation number
  \oldsection}% Regular \section
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
  
\begin{document}
\section*{}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{subsection}{29}
\setcounter{equation}{16}
\subsection{Гл. IV. Жесткие задачи - одношаговые методы} 
\begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\linewidth}
где
\begin{gather}
     K=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
-2 & 1 & & & \\
1 & -2 & 1 & & \\
& 1 & \ddots & \ddots & \\
& & \ddots & -2 & 1 \\
& & & 1 & -2
\end{array}\right).
\end{gather}
   
Собственные значения $K$ известны:
\begin{gather}
       \mu_k=-4\left(\sin \frac{\pi k}{2 N+2}\right)^2
\end{gather}
(см.разд.I.6, формула (6.7b)). Следовательно, двукратные собственные значения второф матрицы в право части (2.16) равны
\begin{gather}
       -\frac{4 \alpha}{(\Delta x)^2}\left(\sin \frac{\pi k}{2 N+2}\right)^2=-4 \alpha(N+1)^2\left(\sin \frac{\pi k}{2 N+2}\right)^2
\end{gather}
причем они находятся между $-4 \alpha(N+1)^2$ и нулем. Поскольку эта матрица симметричная, ее собственные значения хорошо обусловлены, и первая матрица в правой части (2.16) с много меньшими коэффициентами может рассматриваться как малое возмущение. Следовательно, собственные значения $J$ в (2.16) будут оставаться вблизи собственных значений невозмущенной матрицы и находиться в полосе, прилегающеи к отрезку $\left[-4 \alpha(N+1)^2, 0\right]$. Вычисления для $N=40$ показывают, например, что наибольшее отрицательное собственное значение $J$ меняется между -133.3 и -134.9 , в то время как невозмущенное значение равно $-4 \cdot 41^2 \cdot \sin ^2(40 \pi / 82) / 50=-134.28$. Так как большая часть областей устоичивости для ODEX оканчивается вблизи -5.5 на вещественнон оси (рис. 2.3), это приводит к тому, что для $N=40 \boldsymbol{h} \leq 0.04$ и число шагов должно быть $\geq 250$ (ср. с табл. 1.1).
Чтобы объяснить поведение уравнения колебанић стержня, линеаризуем его в окрестности решения $\theta_k=\dot{\theta}_k=0, F_x=F_y=0$. Тогда (1.10') примет вид
\begin{gather}
    G \ddot{\theta}=n^4\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
-3 & 1 & & & \\
1 & -2 & 1 & & \\
& 1 & \ddots & \ddots & \\
& & \ddots & -2 & 1 \\
& & & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right) \theta
\end{gather}
так как при $\theta=0$ имеем $A=G$ и $B=0$. Подставляя теперь $G^{-1}$ из (1.16), заметим, что элементы рассматриваемых матриц (за исключением двух) совпадают с элементами $\pm K$ из (2.17). Поэтому мы аппроксимируем (2.20) уравнением
\begin{gather}
    \ddot{\theta}=-n^4 K^2 \theta
\end{gather}
\end{minipage}

 
\end{document}


how i can write the number 30 in top right like in this page if we take like a subsection

Welcome! I've formatted your code for you. You can do this by highlighting it and using the {} button or ctrl-k.

Isn't that the page number? In the image, I mean. That looks like a pretty standard header with the section/chapter/subsection (don't know which) number and title and the page number on the right.
